# UserContext only works when manually navigating to a page, not when it is automatically done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework

This is part of my code. The `login` function I use in an `onClick` button:

```
const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext)
    
    const login = () => {
    
        const errors = validateForm(fields);
        setErrors(errors);

        if (!errors.length) {
        const username = fields.find((field) => field.id === 'username').input.state.value;
        const password = fields.find((field) => field.id == 'password').input.state.value;
        setUser(username);
        APIService.LoginUser({username, password})

        
        }
    }
```

It basically checks in the `validateForm(fields)` whether the user put something in the form. If there are no errors there, then it sets the user variable to be whatever the user inputted as the username. And that user I hope to be made available to other pages so the app knows who is logged in.

This is the `APIService.LoginUser()` code:

```
export default class APIService {

  static LoginUser(username, password) {
    
    return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/userlookup`, {
      'method':'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(username, password)

    })
    .then(resp => window.location.href = "profile")
    .catch(error => console.log('error time!', username, password))
  }
```

The idea is that once the user is logged in successfully, the site will go straight to the "profile" page. On the profile page I have a simple greeting:

```
const Profile = () => {

    const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <IonPage>
        <IonContent>
            <h1>
            Hi, {user}
            </h1>
        </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    )


};

export default Profile;
```

(from the tags, you can see that this is an ionic app, but I believe that is irrelevant)

My problem is that when I try to log in using the above code, after I get redirected to the `profile` page the greeting does not update with the username of the user that is logged in. However when I comment out this section of the `LoginUser` function:

```
    .then(resp => window.location.href = "profile")
    .catch(error => console.log('error time!', username, password))
```

and manually navigate to the `profile` page, it works correctly! It greets the logged in user! Is this an async problem? My theory is that when it automatically redirects to the `profile` page it does it too fast for the UseContext to tell it what to do? Is this theory true? Is it something else? How do I troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "profile"
```

that is not the correct way to navigate to different pages in Ionic Framework

```
const history = useHistory()
```

and then to go to another route

```
history.push("/profile")
```

See documentation - https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation#ionreactrouter

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: "``React Hook "useHistory" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function``"  To my understanding the `static` method only works with class components.  Are you saying the proper way to do this is to try and change my class component (which I don't really understand that well, but I used code from youtube example) to a functional component so that I can use `history.push("/profile")`?

Comment: sorry i read it wrong, what I would do is route in the  function that made I the login request. If the request is successful then `history.push("/profile")`

Comment: I think what you're saying is that log in function is a functional component so I can just do everything that is in `LoginUser` in that functional component.  I could be wrong

Comment: Figured it out!  I just put it in a functional component and it works great